# How can I disable/enable submit button after jQuery Validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to disable the submit button of the form after the "on_click" event, this jscript does it succesfully, but when a incorrect email is validated with jquery and then pressed the submit button, after I make the correction of the email, the button still is disabled. How can i solve this!?

Jscript:

```
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>    
<script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
<script>
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
        signupForm.submit();
    }
});

$().ready(function() {
    //Desactiva el submit
    $(".submit").click(function () {
       $(".submit").attr("disabled", true);
       $('#signupForm').submit();
     });

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        wrapper: "div",
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Use una cuenta de correo v&aacute;lida",
            password: {
                required: "Ingrese su contraseña",
                minlength: "La contrase&ntilde;a al menos debe tener 5 caracteres"
            }
        }
    });


});
</script>
```

Form

```
    <form class="cmxform" id="signupForm" method="get" action="an-olvido-contrasena.asp">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="inicializar">
                    <p>
                    <div >
                    Correo electr&oacute;nico<br>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Tu correo electr&oacute;nico" <%if creado<>"1" then%>autofocus<%else%> value="<%=vEmail%>" <%end if%>><br>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Aceptar"><br>
                    </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: @Artemination.this is a good question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot disable the button on the `click` event; because if the form is still invalid when you click the button, you will not be able to click it again.  You can only disable it *after* the form has successfully passed validation.

Use the plugin's `submitHandler` option for this as it's fired on a button click only when the form has passed validation.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#signupForm").validate({
        wrapper: "div",
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Use una cuenta de correo v&aacute;lida",
            password: {
                required: "Ingrese su contraseña",
                minlength: "La contrase&ntilde;a al menos debe tener 5 caracteres"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // <- pass 'form' argument in
            $(".submit").attr("disabled", true);
            form.submit(); // <- use 'form' argument here.
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

**NOTES:**

1. `$().ready(function() {...` [**is not recommended** as per jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  Use `$(document).ready(function() {...` or `$(function() {...` instead.
2. You do not need the `required` inline HTML attribute when you've already declared the `required` rule within `.validate()`.
3. Your `submitHandler` within `setDefaults()` was broken.  The `signupForm.submit()` line will do nothing because `signupForm` is an undefined variable.  Define `submitHandler` within `.validate()` and use the `form` argument as provided by the developer.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6foLxzmc/13/**

Comment: @Sparky.nice explanation.you have saved lot of time.thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Bind to the `submit` event instead of to the button click.

```
$('#signupForm').submit(function(){
   $(this).find('.submit').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Alternatively do the disabling in `submitHandler` option of plugin

Comment: Best to leave it to the `submitHandler` within the plugin.  Otherwise, your `submit()` handler will interfere with or bypass validation entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an access to a form validation initialization this approach can help:

```
            jQuery('#form').on('submit', function () {
                if (jQuery(this).data('form_is_invalid')) {
                    jQuery(this).data('form_is_invalid', false);
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            }).on('invalid-form.validate', function () {
                jQuery(this).data('form_is_invalid', true);
            });
```