# Disable submit button when form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, disable-link

I am using this validation code, I want to disable submit button when form submit after validation.
**Submit Button:**

```
<input type="submit" class="submitStandard" value="Save Info" >
```

**Validation code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
                $(".submitStandard").on('click', function() {
                    $('form').validate({
                        ignore: [],
                        rules: {
                            required: {
                                required: true
                            },
                            shopname: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },
                        highlight: function(element) {
                            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                        },
                        unhighlight: function(element) {
                            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                        },
                        errorElement: 'span',
                        errorClass: 'help-block',
                        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                            } else {
                                error.insertAfter(element); 
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });//]]>
            </script>
```

Any best possible solution, submit should be disable when there is not any validation error.

**Problem:** When I Save info, If I click on submit button twice or three time, It save value twice or three, It should be click once, then it should be disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
$(this).prop("disabled", true);
```

Full Code:

```
$(".submitStandard").on('click', function() {
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  $('form').validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
      required: {
        required: true
      },
      shopname: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element); 
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Or on `submit` event of the `<form>`:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find(".submitStandard").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**Note:** I can see that you are using a generic `$("form")`. This is not recommended since when the JavaScript loads, it blindly applies for all the `<form>` elements. So it is better to give an `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **[`submitHandler`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler)** property of `validate` as below:

```
$(".submitStandard").on('click', function() {
  var button=$(this);
  $('form').validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
      required: {
        required: true
      },
      shopname: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    //.. Other properties
    //..
    submitHandler: function(form) {
         if(form.valid()) //check if form is valid?
         {
             button.prop("disabled", true);
         }
    },
    //..
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<form id="registrationfrm" method="post">
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" name="submit" value='SAVE' /> 
</form>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$("#registrationfrm").on("submit",function(){
$("#submitbtn").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try so-

```
$('form#id').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[How can I disable/enable submit button after jQuery Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775875/how-can-i-disable-enable-submit-button-after-jquery-validation)